# Using OFFSet clause with Except in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, fetch, offset

I'm trying to use this offset by I can't seem to understand where this offset would fit.

Any help will be appreciated

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_bidLossModified]
    @current_winner varchar (30), 
    @limit varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        vehicle_id, bid_value 
    FROM 
        auctionDetails 
    WHERE 
        current_winner = @current_winner 
    OFFSET (@limit - 1)*10 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

    EXCEPT 

    SELECT  
        vehicle_id, MAX(bid_value)
    FROM    
        auctionDetails 
    WHERE 
        status = '0' 
    GROUP BY 
        vehicle_id
END
```

Comment: `OFFSET ... FETCH....` needs to be on an `ORDER BY` clause - without any ordering, it doesn't make any sense to skip records ....

Comment: yeah i know that i just uploaded an incomplete code here anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to use a subquery:

```
SELECT ad.*
FROM ((SELECT vehicle_id, bid_value
       FROM auctionDetails
       WHERE current_winner=@current_winner 
       ) except
       (SELECT  vehicle_id, MAX(bid_value)
        FROM auctionDetails 
        WHERE status = 0   -- probably a number so removed quotes
        GROUP BY vehicle_id
       )
      ) ad
ORDER BY vehicle_id, bid_value
OFFSET  (@limit - 1)*10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```